# How to restrict a agent in Jenkins to run only one job?

Tags: jenkins, agent, restriction

I have a Jenkins master without any extra agents. My Jenkins server is having more than 100 jobs and all of them are checked into source control as a Jenkinsfile.

All the Jenkinsfile contains the below at the begging of the file,

```
agent any
```

Now, I want to add one agent to the master and create one job. This newly created job has to run only on the newly added agent machine.

We can restrict a job in Jenkins to run on a particular agent, but in that case I have to modify my all 100 Jenkinsfile to make them run only on master.

Is there a way in Jenkins we can restrict an agent to run a particular job? So that I don't need to modify all the 100 Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understand you correctly...

You can add a `label` to your new job, and have the new node set to `Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node`... then add the same label to that node and it will only execute jobs matching that.

Comment: got you, but i have more than 100 existing jobs, which tells run on any agent.. i dont want that existing jobs to run on the new agent..

Comment: Yeah I think the existing jobs won't run on the new node if you set `Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node` as `any` indicates to run on any _available_ node... but the new node won't be available to those jobs anymore. This is untested though so I may be wrong. If so, you will need to edit all the existing jobs I'm afraid.